# How do I make one of four lights on a switched circuit permanently on?

Tags: electrical

I have floods on the corners of my detached garage that are switched by one switch in a three gang box inside the door.  The other two switches control coach lamps and inside lights.  This are single pole arrangements.  I put a Ring camera and light set in place of one of the floods.  This requires constant power.  How do I make the power to one of them constant and the other three remain on the switch?
There is a circuit breaker just for the four floods and it appears the power comes into the three gang box.  Thank you!!

Comment: Can you re-run the cables from the switch box onwards?

Comment: Can you post a picture of the inside of the switch box?

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the floods to dusk-to-dawn or motion detection lights. Then wire the circuit always-on and bypass the switch or jumper it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is available what is called a wireless switch kit.  Several online merchants offer them.  You simply wire your existing lights and now the new camera location hot full time. Then wire up and install the switching device at each light location and leave them in the electrical box behind each fixture. Then install the switches in the house at a convenient location. P.